# Amazon S3 PutObject is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I am placing files into an S3 storage using the below code.  I am finding it is exceedingly slow.  The stopwatch indicated 18 seconds+.  Any suggests or other experiences?

```
        // upload the file to S3
        AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKey);

        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceFileName, FileMode.Open);

        request.WithInputStream(fs);
        request.WithBucketName(bucketName);
        request.WithKey(keyName);
        Stopwatch stp1 = new Stopwatch();
        stp1.Start();
        client.PutObject(request);
        stp1.Stop();
        fs.Close();
```

This code is C#.  I am using the amazon .net sdk.

The file is only 56K in size and my upload bandwidth is 1.87Mbps.

Comment: How big is the thing you're uploading? 18s would be very fast for 1TB.

Comment: How large is the file, and what's your Internet upload bandwidth?

Comment: The file is 56K and my bandwidth is 1.5mbps upload

Comment: Over 10 years later and still having issues with upload speeds to S3.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds very similar to a problem I had recently, which was caused by the automatic proxy detection settings in "Internet Options" on Windows.

The Amazon SDK uses `WebRequest` to make it's HTTP requests and by default `WebRequest` adheres to the computer's "Internet Option" settings for detecting local proxies. Luckily `WebRequest` has a static property `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` which, when set to `null`, removes the automatic proxy detection.

All you need to do is set it to `null` before you start using `AmazonS3`:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null; // here

AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretAccessKey);

[...]
```

It's worth noting that this static property only needs to be set once per application domain and not every time you want to create an `AmazonS3` object.

**Alternate approach:**

If you don't mind reconfiguring the machine, is to go to:

```
Windows Control Panel > Internet Options > Connections > Lan Settings
```

and un-check "Automatically detect settings".  If you use this approach, you do not need to set the `DefaultWebProxy` property at all.

**Further info:**

When I encountered the issue I asked the following question on SO:

[How to turn off the automatic proxy detection in the `AmazonS3` object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8971210/191693)

It has more details than my answer here if your interested.

Comment: had the same problem too! thanks for the answer - this knocks 15 seconds off of my program now..

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the BufferSize on the AmazonS3Config

```
var config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    BufferSize = 65536 // 64KB Use a larger buffer size, normally 8K default.
};
```

Comment: I tried http, multipart, but nothing really put a major dent in the upload speed like adjusting the BufferSize.  BufferSize increases my upload speed by 5x.

Answer (score 0):

My newest project is built on **.Net 6** and the **AWSSDK.S3** Nuget package.

Application startup was blazing fast, but first use / instance creation (through injection) took something like 8 to 10 seconds.

What did the trick for me was setting the `DefaultConfigurationMode` in `Program.cs`.

```
var awsOptions = builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
awsOptions.DefaultConfigurationMode = DefaultConfigurationMode.Standard;

[...]

builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsOptions);
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonS3>();
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!